# How to store data with backingfield in EF Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, backing-field

I have the following class

```
public class InvestorsLottery : Lottery 
{
    [Column(TypeName = "decimal(14, 2)")]
    public decimal Investment { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int Percentage { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Column(TypeName = "decimal(30, 18)")]
    public decimal InvestmentEth 
    { 
        get { return _investmentEth; } 
        set { 
             _investmentEth = Investment / EthPrice; 
             value = _investmentEth
        } 
    }
    private decimal _investmentEth;
}
```

with the following fluent api

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(builder);

    builder.Entity<InvestorsLottery>()
           .Property(p => p.InvestmentEth)
           .HasField("_investmentEth")
           .UsePropertyAccessMode(PropertyAccessMode.Field);
}
```

but the value of InvestmentEth stays zero - how can I change this?

Comment: Your setter for `InvestmentEth` is wrong. It should have `value` in its body. [guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/properties)

Comment: started to mess around thanks but still it doesnt save the value

Comment: does adding the backingfield attribute help? [BackingField(nameof(_investmentEth))] to the InvestmentEth property

Comment: see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/backing-field?tabs=data-annotations

Comment: Additionally, the docs seem to point to it assigning directly to the backing field which is likely also what you want as you'd probably not want to do maths on the property as it comes out of the DB

Comment: It may be a better option to turn this into a [computed column](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/generated-properties?tabs=data-annotations#computed-columns) in the database. That solves all kinds of possible redundancy conflicts.

Comment: Why do you want to go through all these steps? Like Gert mentioned, add it as a computed column OR just add another property that is marked as [NotMapped]. All entity classes are marked partial. You can add as many members as you want without affecting the migration.

Comment: Could you give me an example of a computed column with sql query? @MayurEkbote